# Angular CLI not rendering Component elements correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, generate

I am experiencing a weird issue related to Angular CLI which seems not creating components correctly for causes unknown. When I write "ng generate component modal" or I use the IntelliJ Angular CLI tool, the result is in a bad rendering of the component.ts files.

Have a look here, please:

```js
import {Component, OnInit

< %
if (!!viewEncapsulation) { %>,
  ViewEncapsulation < %
}
%>
< %
if (changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy < %
}
%>
}
from
'@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-modal', < % if
(inlineTemplate)
{ %>
  template: `
    <p>
      form-modal works!
    </p>
  `, < %
}
else
{ %>
  templateUrl: './form-modal.component.html', < %
}
if (inlineStyle) { %>
  styles: [] < %
} else { %>
  styleUrls: ['./form-modal.component.css'] < %
}
%>
< %
if (!!viewEncapsulation) { %>,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation. < %= viewEncapsulation % > < %
}
if (changeDetection !== 'Default') { %>,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy. < %= changeDetection % > < %
}
%>
})
export class
< %= classify(name) % > Component
implements
OnInit
{

  constructor()
  {
  }

  ngOnInit()
  {
  }

}
```

Can you please explain me what weirdeness it is? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```html
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

As requested I added also the result of `ng --v`.

Consider that this project has been imported as webapp child folder in a bigger Java application. I can run the Angular App properly with `ng serve --open`.

Comment: Can you post your global npm packages as well as your project package.json? (Just the angular related packages to look at versions)

Comment: Or just type `ng --v`.